# How to access request in helper functions

Tags: python, flask

Say you want to redirect a user if they are not logged in. Currently I have this:

```
def my_account():
    if "user" not in session or not session["user"]:
        return redirect('/')

    ...

def my_favourites():
    if "user" not in session or not session["user"]:
        return redirect('/')

    ...
```

But now I would like to reuse the code that checks if a user is logged in. But this requires the `session` object.

I'm not sure if I could or should pass the `request` or `session` object explicitly in a helper function. Or if there is yet another more preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write re-usable code to verify if a user is logged in, one recommended way is to use decorators on the view functions. For example,

```
@login_required
def do_something():
*    pass
```

Then, you can define this decorator below. You can then use your `request` and `session` object. Also, this will redirect to the login url if user is not logged in already and then forward to the next page once logged in.

```
def login_required(f):
*    @wraps(f)
*    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
*        if "user" not in session or not session["user"]:
*            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
*        return f(*args, **kwargs)
*    return decorated_function
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://packages.python.org/Flask-Login/ ? I believe this is a package that will provide what you are looking for easier.

Comment: I have had a look. At the moment I wish to "roll my own" and try to get a deeper understanding of Flask. Also, I want to know how to do this in a general case, not necessarily to do with authentication/autorisation.